# JSON.NET throwing exception on missing comma

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I am using JSON.NET to de-serialize a json file, very rarely there is a file within which a field may not have a trailing comma after its value. this causes an excpetion becaue it expects a comma.  I was looking over JSON.NET documentation and could not find an option where I could specify to still parse that field.

Is there a way in JSON.NET to not worry about trailing comma?

Below, if lets say if a field does not contain a comma at its end, an exception is thrown.

```
 {
        "Rack": "0015",
        "SampleType": "Specimen",
        "SID": "HBSAG-PC",
        "Position": 4,
        "AssayNumber": 149,
    "AssayVersion": 5,
        "Dilution": 1,
        "Replicate": 5
    "Track": 1,
    "Lane": 1,
        "ReagentMasterLot": "08559LF00",
        "ReagentSerialNumber": 65000,
        "Comment": "HBSAG Q IIPC"
    }
```

Comment: Well the missing comma is not at the last element; it's at the second-to-last element. So, that's not valid Json even if JSON.NET has an option to ignore a trailing comma, and it *should* throw an exception.

Comment: This is like asking an XML parser to parse invalid XML. I'd be astonished if it were feasible. JSON is meant to be computer-generated - if whatever's generating your files is broken, fix it.

Comment: Your example input is not JSON. Why would you expect a JSON parser to give you meaningful output from it?

Comment: look at my sample again, it parses fine, but lets says where you see the field "Replicate" if I remove the comma after its value 5 I will get an exception. My question is is there away to ignora traling comma

Comment: @tamtam No. Is this answer enough?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [JSON spec](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) requires that name/value pairs within an object have commas between them.  (See also [JSON.org](http://json.org/)).  If the commas are missing, the JSON is invalid.  Therefore, any standards-conforming parser is going to throw an exception, including JSON.Net.  There is no option to ignore missing commas.  You need to fix the JSON at the source.

Answer (score 1):

The JSON you've posted is invalided. Not because of the trailing comma at the end, but a missing comma in the center

```
{
    "Rack": "0015",
    "SampleType": "Specimen",
    "SID": "HBSAG-PC",
    "Position": 4,
    "AssayNumber": 149,
    "AssayVersion": 5,
    "Dilution": 1,
    "Replicate": 5
    "Track": 1,
    "Lane": 1,
    "ReagentMasterLot": "08559LF00",
    "ReagentSerialNumber": 65000,
    "Comment": "HBSAG Q IIPC"
}
```

This line `"Replicate": 5"Track": 1,` is missing a comma between the '5' and "Track".

The corrected Json looks like this:

```
{
    "Rack": "0015",
    "SampleType": "Specimen",
    "SID": "HBSAG-PC",
    "Position": 4,
    "AssayNumber": 149,
    "AssayVersion": 5,
    "Dilution": 1,
    "Replicate": 5,
    "Track": 1,
    "Lane": 1,
    "ReagentMasterLot": "08559LF00",
    "ReagentSerialNumber": 65000,
    "Comment": "HBSAG Q IIPC"
}
```

You can validate your JSON with [JSONLint](http://jsonlint.com/).

Comment: OP already knows it *`see the field "Replicate" if I remove the comma after its value 5 I will get an exception`*

Comment: @L.B ahh, missed that. Thanks.